# JQuery checkbox selector which are not in a specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am breaking my head trying to make it work. I think the solution is not that hard to find but my brain will explode soon...

So I have a bunch of div with the class `process`

Inside each div, I have a variable amount of checkbox.

I want to to trigger an event when all the checkbox are checked BUT the ones inside the last `process` class.

This is the base

```
if(!$(':checkbox').not(':checked').length > 0)
{
  //All checkbox are checked
}
```

So I tried to

```
if(!$(':checkbox').not('.process:last').not(':checked').length > 0)
```

But this is not the solution.

Comment: Show your HTML, so that we can guide you better.

Comment: @Raccoon can you give a js fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, I assume the following HTML and found you the solution:

```js
$(function () {
  $(".check").click(function () {
    alert($(".process:not(.process:last)").find(":checkbox").length == $(".process:not(.process:last)").find(":checkbox:checked").length ? "Yes" : "No");
  });
  $(".check_all").click(function () {
    $(".process").find(":checkbox").prop("checked", true);
  });
  $(".check_no_last").click(function () {
    $(".process:not(.process:last)").find(":checkbox").prop("checked", true);
  });
});
```

```css
label {display: inline-block; margin: 5px 25px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<div class="process">
  <div>Process #1
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="" id=""> Checkbox 1</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="" id=""> Checkbox 2</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="" id=""> Checkbox 3</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="process">
  <div>Process #2
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="" id=""> Checkbox 1</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="" id=""> Checkbox 2</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="" id=""> Checkbox 3</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="process">
  <div>Process #3
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="" id=""> Checkbox 1</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="" id=""> Checkbox 2</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="" id=""> Checkbox 3</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="process">
  <div>Process #4
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="" id=""> Checkbox 1</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="" id=""> Checkbox 2</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="" id=""> Checkbox 3</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="process">
  <div>Process #5
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="" id=""> Checkbox 1</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="" id=""> Checkbox 2</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="" id=""> Checkbox 3</label>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Check All" class="check_all" />
<input type="submit" value="Check But Last" class="check_no_last" />
<input type="submit" value="Check" class="check" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```js
$('div.process:last input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    var countOfAllCheckboxes = $(this).parent().find(':checkbox');
    var countOfAllCheckedCheckboxes = countOfAllCheckboxes.filter(':checked');
    if(countOfAllCheckedCheckboxes.length == countOfAllCheckboxes.length) {
        alert('All checkboxes are checked in last div.process!');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="process">
  <input type="checkbox" name="chk" /> Checkbox1 in First Div
</div>
<div class="process">
  <input type="checkbox" name="chk"/> Checkbox1 in Last Div.process
  <input type="checkbox" name="chk"/> Checkbox2 in Last Div.process
<div>
```